# need to filter all the records less than current month using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to filter records less than a current month using VBA.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:L").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<" & MonthName(Month(Date))
```

I have tried this but didn't get the desired result.

please suggest how can we filter the required data using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Less than the current month means **before the first** of the current month:

```
Sub Macro2()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:L").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<3/1/2020", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

The above is for a specific month/year.  In general:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim crit As String

    crit = "<" & DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("A:L").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlAnd
    End With
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]